# Disable <a class button if input fields empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I know it's easy to do using < button > or < input type="submit" but how would you keep this button disabled unless both input fields are filled?

```
<input id="one" type="text">
<input id="two" type="text">
<a href="#" class="button">OK</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tie an event to both inputs, and check that both have values.  Then enable the link.

```
$('#one, #two').blur(function() {
   if($('#one').val() !== "" && $('#two').val() !== "") {
       $('.button').attr('href','#');
   } else {
      $('.button').removeAttr('href');
   }
});
```

and change your html to:

```
<a class="button">OK</a>
```

so that the link is disabled on page load.  Here's a [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x6sokkcu/).

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       //$(".button").attr('disabled', "disabled");
        $(".button").click(function(){
           one = $("#one").val();
           two = $("#two").val();
           if(one && two){
             ///both fields filled. 
             return true;
           }
           //one or both of them is empty
                  
 
          return false;
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="one" type="text">
<input id="two" type="text">
<a href="#" class="button">OK</a>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `two = $("two").val( )`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $inputs = $('#one,#tow');
  $inputs.change(check);
  $submit = $('#submit');

  function check() {
    var result = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < $inputs.length; i++) {
      if (!$inputs[i].value) {
        result = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (result) {
      $submit.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }

  check();
});
```

suggest use angular form

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation if facing this kind of situation.
First, am add disabled class onto anchor tag on page load by using this style :

```
.disabled {
  color : gray // gray out button color
  cursor : default; // make cursor to arrow
  // you can do whatever styling you want
  // even disabled behaviour
}
```

We add those class using jquery on document ready together with keyup event like so :

```
$(function () {

   // add disabled class onto button class(anchor tag)
   $(".button").addClass('disabled');

   // register keyup handler on one and two element
   $("#one, #two").keyup(function () {

      var one = $("#one").val(),
          two = $("#two").val();
      // checking if both not empty, then remove class disabled
      if (one && two) $(".button").removeClass('disabled');
      // if not then add back disabled class
      else $(".button").addClass('disabled');

   });

   // when we pressing those button
   $('.button').click(function (e) {
     // we check if those button has disabled class yet
     // just return false
     if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) return false;
   });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/jxttw4dp/)